# How to call java paintComponent using repaint

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent, repaint

In [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAWTh9KftN0&t=5m20s) video `drawing()` method is called in main class. When we remove `drawing()` in the main method it still draws the shape. How can we avoid this situation ?

shapes class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class shapes{
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    draw object = new draw();
    frame.add(object);

    object.drawing();
    }

}
```

Draw class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class draw extends JPanel{
public void drawing(){
    repaint();
}
public void paintComponent(){
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  g.fillRect(10,15,100,100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some minor issues with the code, but I assume that it's only a small snippet for demonstration purposes. For details, have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

Actually, this tutorial would also answer your question, but to summarize it:

The `paintComponent` method will be called automatically, "by the operating system", whenever the component has to be repainted. The call to `repaint()` only tells the operating system to call `paintComponent` again, as soon as possible. So you can call `repaint()` to make sure that something that you canged appears on the screen as soon as possible.

If you explicitly want to enable/disable certain painting operations, you can not influence this by preventing `paintComponent` from being called. It will be called anyhow. Instead, you'll introduce some flag or state indicating whether something should be painted or not.

In your example, this could *roughly* be done like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw extends JPanel{
    private boolean paintRectangle = false;

    void setPaintRectangle(boolean p) {
        paintRectangle = p;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (paintRectangle) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(10,15,100,100);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call the `setPaintRectangle` method to indicate whether the rectangle should be painted or not.